# Some question about IDA

Tags: ida, hexrays

This binary was from a CTF challenge.

I found 2 way to solve this, one is run & debug the bin, set a break point and see result in flag after the bin running, another is trying to understand the function.

There are some parts that i dont understand even when i solved this challenge :

Why my IDA reverse the string (v6 should be "Bkav" and v7 + v8 should be "Security"

As you see, it pass the char* v6 ("Bkav") into the func01 and func02, but when i do the same thing, it give wrong flag. But when i try to pass the "BkavSecurity" in to func01 and func02, it give me right flag. Quite confuse about this.

[image]

You can find file here : https://www.sendspace.com/file/g7w8nz

Comment: please give this question a more meaningful title

Comment: You're passing a flag? Where? It's not clear to me what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that what you're passing is an address. And the address of `v6` and since `v6`,`v7` and `v8` are adjacent to each other so any method that works on `char *` will read from one to the other until it reaches byte `0`.

```
Letter |  Address | Variable
   B   | ebp-7e5h | -> v6 (4 bytes)
   k   | ebp-7e4h | 
   a   | ebp-7e3h | 
   v   | ebp-7e2h | 
   S   | ebp-7e1h | -> v7 (4 bytes)
   e   | ebp-7e0h |
   c   | ebp-7dfh |
   u   | ebp-7deh |
   r   | ebp-7ddh | -> v8 (4 bytes)
   i   | ebp-7dch |
   t   | ebp-7dbh |
   y   | ebp-7dah |
  \0   | ebp-7d9h | -> v9 (1 byte)
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can create a **stackvar K**   on all the four instructions and convert those stack variables to an array of proper length

then you can see ida showing you the offsets from base the screen shot is from ida free 5 on a 32 bit machine  (it doesn't decompile )

but in your case i think decompilation would be more better ( this construct is an inlined/unrolled strcpy(src,dest)

[image]